# How to import beans using the migrate module?

Tags: migrations, blocks

The migrate module allows you to migrate many different kinds of content with what it calls Destination Classes. However i don't see support for beans in there.

I've searched in https://drupal.org/project/migrate_extras and https://drupal.org/project/issues/migrate_extras?categories=All to no avail. So my question is how would i go about importing beans into my DB?

For the moment i've been using bean_create, however I believe an implementation that hooks into migrate would be better.

The default Destination Classes are https://drupal.org/node/1006988

Answer (score 1):

This forum post shows an example DestinationHandler and Migration

https://drupal.org/node/2141211

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking to do this from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8, this is how it can be done: https://github.com/npinos/d7migrate